# Regex selects first to last instead of just first

Tags: html, ruby, regex, tags, rubular

I'm trying to use String.sub! in ruby and it substitutes way too much.

The regex i'm using. You can see it's matching too much: http://rubular.com/r/IUav4KEFWH

```
<rb>.+<\/rb>
```

it selects from the first  to the last  and I want it just to select the first pair.
is there another version of sub I'm not aware of, or a better way to sub

it would be easy to turn of multi-line and put them on separate lines but I don't want to sacrifice multi-lining

Comment: Please put your code in your question. It's OK to have the link as well, but questions should be able to survive broken links.

Answer (score 1):

Your regex is too greedy:

```
<rb>.+<\/rb>
```

Make it non-greedy using:

```
<rb>.+?<\/rb>
```

#### [Rubular Demo](http://rubular.com/r/xtfjp3LSy0)

Answer (score 1):

It matches from the first `<rb>` tag up until the very last `</rb>` tag because `+` is a [**greedy**](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-greed.html) operator meaning it will match as much as it can and still allow the remainder of the regular expression to match.

You want to use `+?` for a non-greedy match meaning "one or more — preferably as few as possible".

```
<rb>.+?</rb>
```

**Note:** A parser to extract from HTML is recommended rather than using regular expression.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this variant:

```
<rb>(?>(?!<\/rb>).)*+<\/rb>
```

[Demo](http://rubular.com/r/uitiHNUSoj)

Or if you want:

```
<rb>[^<]+<\/rb>
```

[Demo](http://rubular.com/r/7PmcyMiKka)

See the difference between `.*?` And `[^<]+` in this [DEMO](http://rubular.com/r/5sgWsXmhmZ)